# How to convert a structure to byte*

Tags: c++, windows

While trying to convert my structure to byte* :

```
objNDSDriver.StartFn((byte*)objSTNDSFTPDriverInfo);
```

I am getting the error:

> error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'STNDSFTPDriverInfo' to 'byte *'

Comment: It would behoove you to obtain a [good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Is `STNDSFTPDriverInfo` a pointer type or is it a structure/class?

Comment: @James McNellis, Sure , ll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take the address of your structure, and probably use the [reinterpret_cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) operator:

```
objNDSDriver.StartFn(reinterpret_cast<byte *>(&objSTNDSFTPDriverInfo));
```

Comment: Thanks , Itz working now, But Why the refernce is typecasted not the obj itself? I just want to know as I am startin up with C

Comment: @Subhen, since you want to treat `objSTNDSFTPDriverInfo` as an array of bytes, its *address* should be cast, not its value.

Comment: & in this case means the address. And there is no reference in C, so you mean C++.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
objNDSDriver.StartFn((byte*)&objSTNDSFTPDriverInfo);
```